# React Native - StackNavigator header has double height

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, expo

I have a similar issue as [After upgrading to expo SDK 37.0.0 my stackNavigator header doubled in height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61582383/after-upgrading-to-expo-sdk-37-0-0-my-stacknavigator-header-doubled-in-height), however I had the same problem with Expo SDK 36. I tried to upgrade Expo (37.0.0) and react-navigation version, but it had no effect on the header.

```
"react-navigation": "^3.13.0",
"react-navigation-drawer": "^1.4.0",
"react-navigation-stack": "^1.7.3",
"react-navigation-tabs": "^1.2.0",
```

I have an authentication switch (As in react-navigation [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/3.x/auth-flow/)), which then routes to a stack above the BottomTabNavigator. In this way I can have a screen rendered over the bottom bar. Then I have a list of stacks in the BottomTabNavigator.

```
// Main appNavigator
export default createAppContainer(
    createAnimatedSwitchNavigator({
        AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
        Auth: AuthStack,
        App: AboveBottomTabStack,
    }, {
        initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
    })
);

// Components routed here are ABOVE bottom tab navigator
const AboveBottomTabStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Tabs: {
            screen: MainTabNavigator,
            navigationOptions: {
                // Hides the header, in this case the headers of the Stack components inside TabNavigator are shown
                header: null,
            }
        },
        ReportScreen: ReportScreen
    }
);

// Components routed here are UNDER bottom tab navigator
const MainTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    HomeStack: HomeStack,
    ReportListStack: ReportListStack,
    SettingsStack: SettingsStack,
});

// One of the stacks inside the TabNavigator
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Dashboard: {
            screen: DashboardScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
                headerStyle: {
                    //backgroundColor:'#00beb8',
                    height: 0,  // Even with height 0 the header is displayed
                }
            }
        },
    }
);
```

I tried in setting the last stack's header to null (the one in HomeStack for example), and the header actually hides. The problem is the size, even if the height is set to 0, a small portion of header is displayed, you can see pictures in the linked question at the top.

Comment: For your future, use react-navigation 5.x

Comment: Do you think that upgrading it to 5.x could solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok with the help of a friend we managed to find the solution to this problem.
Using the following prop in the navigation options fixed the issue for us:

```
 navigationOptions: {
            headerForceInset: { vertical: 'never' },
        }
```

From what I understood from react-navigation [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/3.x/handling-iphonex/) it creates a SafeAreaView component around the app's content, however why does it create this annoying small bar on the top is still unknown to me.

EDIT: This prop should be written for android only, because on Iphone it creates graphical issues